# using matrices algebra to manipulate strings: is it feasible?

Tags: string, r, math, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to use matrix algebra with the purpose of manipulating strings. This means being able to multiple matrix-like structures using concatenation and pasting of string or of arrays of strings.

I previously tried to implement the thing on R, but it was not possible as matrices can have only one dimensional entries.

I hope to be enough language-agnostic and abstract, but I'll use R-like code for sake of clarity. I should make explicit that I don't require real matrices, but matrix-like structure on which we can do matrices-like multiplication and retrieve the (ij) element of the structure.

**{+,*} MATRICES MULTIPLICATION**

The {+,*}-product of two square matrices **A** and **B** of dimension n is a matrix **C** defined by the elements:  **C**<sub>i,j</sub> = Sum<sub>k=1,...,n</sub>**A**<sub>i,k</sub> * **B**<sub>k,j</sub>.

For example, consider the matrix  `M <- matrix(c(a,b,0,0,c,d,0,0,e),3,3)`.  Then M times M is  `M <- matrix(c(a^2,a*b+b*c,b*d,0,c^2,c*d+d*e,0,0,e^2),3,3)`.

**{c(,),paste0(,)} MATRICES MULTIPLICATION**

The rule of this operation I would like to implement are the same of the previous stated multiplication with the essential mutation that the sum should be a concatenation and the product should be a paste. In other words, where in the previous formula we found `a+b`, now the output should be "c(a,b)", and when we found `a*b`, now we should read this as `paste0(a,b)`.

Some of the usual properties have to be respected, namely the distributive properties and the 0 element properties. Hence, if `a <- c("q",0,"w")` and `b <- c("e")` then `a*b <- c("qe",0,"we")` (and we should freely forget the 0 element, dropping it as it won't affect the computation.

Moreover, we are multiplying equal-dimensioned matrices, hence each element  **C**<sub>i,j</sub> = Sum<sub>k=1,...,n</sub>**A**<sub>i,k</sub> * **B**<sub>k,j</sub> is now to be read as  `c("A[i,1]B[1,j]",...,"A[i,n]B[n,j]")`.

Finally, the outcome matrix-like structure should be something that we can use again for computations (so for example to make more complex computation as mult(mult(A,B),C) and so on...).

**A SIMPLER CASE**

For simplicity sake, let's start from the computation of product of the form `mult(A,A)`, `mult(mult(A,A),A)` and so on. We may also impose **A** to be a *simple* matrix, meaning that each of its elements are one dimensional string, and not concatenation of string.

Let's give an example. Let's be **A** a 3 dimensional matrix defined as  `A <- matrix(c("a","b",0,0,"c","d",0,0,"e"),3,3)`,  then the multiplication of **A** times **A** should be  `mult(A,A) = matrix(c("aa",c("ab","bc"),"bd",0,"cc",c("cd","de"),0,0,"ee"),3,3)`  and **A**<sup>3</sup> should be  `mult(mult(A,A),A) = matrix(c("aaa",c("aab","abc","bcc"),c("abd","bcd","bde"),0,"ccc",c("ccd","cde","dee"),0,0,"eee"),3,3)`.

**Question**

How would you implement this? Which language seems more fitting?

Comment: What is `c()`? What is `paste0()`? Why should anyone outside of the R community care?

Comment: I should have defined the R functions... `c(a,b,...,n)` returns an array with n elements a, b, ... n; `paste0(abc,def)`, where abc and def are two strings, returns the string `abcdef`. The first function append a vector to another, the second paste together two or more strings.  The code is written in R just because I was working in that language, but the question is a general one, regarding string manipulation under matrix algebra, which is useful in many problems (or may be) and I don't know any language doing that as builtin...

Comment: There's no distributive law under R vector operation rules (shorter vector is repeated to mach longer one's length), nor there is distributive law if you trim to the shorter length instead.

Comment: What do you mean? If I'm not wrong `paste0(c("a","b","c"),"l")` gives `c("al","bl","cl")` which is _similar_ to (a+b+c)*l=al+bl+cl... This is the kind of distributivity which I need.

Comment: Try `paste0(c("a","b","c"),c("1","2"))`.

Comment: Ok, that's why I proposed to solve first the simpler problem where the righthand matrix has only length one vectors. The subsequent generalisation comes checking the length of the righthand multiplicand, breaking the paste0() function in as many parts as the length, and the concatenating them so to keep the distributivity. Hence your example becomes `c(paste0(c("a","b","c"),"1"),paste0(c("a","b","c"),"2"))`.

Comment: Under distributivity your expression should be equal to mine, but it isn't. Unless you redefine either "equal" or "paste0" or "c" or "distributivity", that is. The simplified version is not closed and not associative, even when both sides of `(a×b)×c = a×(b×c)` are defined.

Comment: Distributivity means `(a+b)c = ac+bc`. Do we agree on this? Hence, you're right, when the righthand multiplicand is not of length one, we should pay attention to his length and implement the operation properly (as I explained) because the builtin operation in R don't fit. The simplified case doesn't present this issue, as each element of the right hand side of the operation has length always one, and `paste0(c("a","b","c"),"1")` works properly. So, I'm afraid I can't understand what's your point.

Comment: What operation do you want to implement properly? Both `c` and `paste0` are already defined and implemented. *They* do not obey the distributive law. If you want the distributive law, you should use something other than `c` and `paste0`.

Comment: If instead of `paste0` you use `as.vector(outer(x,y,paste0))`, then `c()` distributes over it and you are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas for symbolic multlipication of matrices in R:

First we need to define the inner product of a row and a column. This can be done with:

```
wrap <- function(x) paste0("(",x,")")

rowcol <- function(row,col) paste(wrap(row),wrap(col),sep="*",collapse="+")
```

Example:

```
> rowcol(c("A","B","C"),c("D","E","F"))
[1] "(A)*(D)+(B)*(E)+(C)*(F)"
```

I had to "wrap" each element in parenthesis beacause the powers greater than 2 may have more comoplicated expressions than a single variable or number (zero). Also, note that zero will show up normally, i.e., it doesn't know (yet) that these can be simplified:

```
> rowcol(c("A","B"),c("0","X+Y"))
[1] "(A)*(0)+(B)*(X+Y)"
```

Since these are valid expressions in R, this fact can be used to write a simplification function to eliminate zeros and redundant parenthesis. I'll get there.

Now the matrix multiplication and powers are simply:

```
symprod <- function(A,B) sapply(1:ncol(B), function(j)sapply(1:nrow(A), function(i)rowcol(A[i,],B[,j])))

sympow <- function(A,n) { B <- A; for( i in seq_len(n-1) ) B <- symprod(B,A); B }
```

They create valid (although clumsy) expressions:

```
> A <- matrix(LETTERS[1:4],2,2)
> diag(A) <- 0
> sympow(A,3)
     [,1]                                          [,2]                                         
[1,] "((0)*(0)+(C)*(B))*(0)+((0)*(C)+(C)*(0))*(B)" "((0)*(0)+(C)*(B))*(C)+((0)*(C)+(C)*(0))*(0)"
[2,] "((B)*(0)+(0)*(B))*(0)+((B)*(C)+(0)*(0))*(B)" "((B)*(0)+(0)*(B))*(C)+((B)*(C)+(0)*(0))*(0)"
```

Now let's talk about simplification. These strings can be parsed into valid R expressions, since they comply to the R standard. The variables need not be defined, because we are not going to evaluate the expressions. Actually I only want to parse them to ease simplification.

Check the function below. It removes redundant parenthesis, replaces zero times anything with zero, and removes parcels (in additions) that are zero:

```
simplify <- function(e)
{
    if( mode(e) %in% c("name","numeric") ) return(e)

    if( as.character(e[[1]])=="+" )
    {
        x <- simplify(e[[2]])

        y <- simplify(e[[3]])

        if( identical(x,0) ) return(y)

        if( identical(y,0) ) return(x)

        return(call("+", x, y))
    }

    if( as.character(e[[1]])=="*" )
    {
        x <- simplify(e[[2]])

        if( identical(x,0) ) return(0)

        y <- simplify(e[[3]])

        if( identical(y,0) ) return(0)

        return(call("*", x, y))
    }

    if( as.character(e[[1]])=="(" )
    {
        x <- simplify(e[[2]])

        if( mode(x) %in% c("name","numeric") ) return(x)

        return(call("(", x))
    }
}
```

This function works with a `call` object. To use with strings we need

```
simplify_text <- function(s) deparse(simplify(parse(text=s)[[1]]))
```

Example:

```
> simplify_text("(x)+(0*(a+b))+(z)")
[1] "x + z"
```

If you want, you can use it as wrapper for `rowcol`:

```
rowcol <- function(row,col) simplify_text(paste(wrap(row),wrap(col),sep="*",collapse="+"))
```

The result is:

```
> sympow(A,3)
     [,1]          [,2]         
[1,] "0"           "(C * B) * C"
[2,] "(B * C) * B" "0"
```

Some other simplifications can be written, it depends on how do plan to work with them. But, if the input matrices are strings of valid expressions, the final result remain valid.

---

EDIT: a different approch for `rowcol`:

Consider these functions:

```
cellprod <- function(r, s)
{
    z <- expand.grid(r,s, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    filter <- (z$Var1 != 0) & (z$Var2 != 0)

    paste(z$Var1[filter], z$Var2[filter], sep="*", collapse="+")
}

rowcol <- function(row,col)
{
    x <- strsplit(row, "\\+")

    y <- strsplit(col, "\\+")

    L <- vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) cellprod(x[[i]],y[[i]]), character(1))

    filter <- nzchar(L)

    if( ! any(filter) ) return("0")

    paste(L[filter], collapse="+")
}
```

Using these instead of the functions above, we can handle matrices with expressions of the form `x*y*z+a*b+f`, i. e., sums of products in each cell. The functions automatically applies the distributive law, preserving the form (sum-of-products) and also removes zeros automatically. The last example above becomes:

```
> sympow(A,3)
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "0"     "C*B*C"
[2,] "B*C*B" "0"
```

No simplification required! Another example:

```
> A <- matrix(LETTERS[1:9],3,3)
> B <- matrix(LETTERS[10:18],3,3)
> A[2,3] <- 0
> A[3,2] <- 0
> B[1,3] <- 0
> B[3,1] <- 0
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "D"  "G" 
[2,] "B"  "E"  "0" 
[3,] "C"  "0"  "I" 
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "J"  "M"  "0" 
[2,] "K"  "N"  "Q" 
[3,] "0"  "O"  "R"
> symprod(A,B)
     [,1]      [,2]          [,3]     
[1,] "A*J+D*K" "A*M+D*N+G*O" "D*Q+G*R"
[2,] "B*J+E*K" "B*M+E*N"     "E*Q"    
[3,] "C*J"     "C*M+I*O"     "I*R"
```

Comment: Wow, it should work! I'll check it in a minute. I'll probably have to work a little bit on the simplification (as part of the sympow function or as a subsequent step, in order to remove all the parentesis and the +). Thanks!

Comment: There may be some situations where you can't remove the plus signs; you may have `"(x * y) + (w * z)"`...

Comment: Yep, but in that case what I want as final output is two string "xy" and "wz" (if it were "((x*y)+(a*b))*z" the desired output is the two string "xyz" and "abz").

Comment: I may explain you the ratio, if you're interested (A possible motivation is computing paths inside a graph, where the strings in position i,j of A^k  are the edge touched in a path of length k from i to j)

Comment: @gvdr, I found a simpler way to get the results in the form you want (always distributing "*" over "+"). See new answer below.