# R remove redundant parentheses from formula string or expression

Tags: string, r, formula, parentheses

I have many formula strings similar to this:

```
str <- "( ((  A  ) *  J ) - ((  J  ) *  G  ) ) /  Z "
```

There are many parentheses which don't need to be there, `(A*J - J*G)/Z` is sufficient. Is there a function or package in R that can take care of this?

I tried functions for R expressions and as well `as.formula` but did not find  what I need.

Comment: Not sure, but try something like this: `gsub("\\(([[:alnum:]]+)\\)", "\\1", gsub(" ", "", str))`. Logic: 1) remove all `spaces` and two look for all `()` and if there are consecutive set of `characters+numerals`, then remove the `paranthesis`, else do nothing. In case it tests well, you can write it down as an answer and mark as such.

Comment: This removes at least the parentheses around A and J: `"((A*J)-(J*G))/Z"`, thanks!

Comment: was sure I overlooked something. got it now.

Comment: In the general case, I doubt it.  You can use @Arun 's method to find redundant "paired" sets like `((foo+(bar)))` but since `J` in your example could easily be some expression whose operator precedence gets fouled up if you don't set it off from `G` , how would you know for certain which single-set parentheses are safe to remove?

Comment: Out of curiosity (and because it may help you get better answers), why?  I don't think R's functions that use formulas, like `lm` or `model.matrix`, care if there are extra parentheses.

Comment: @Aaron: I have to list a few hundred equations from my ODE model in a document for a report.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand; you want to present these as mathematical formulas, not use them as expressions or formulas within R.  Glad you got some solutions that will work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches:

**R parsing**

```
rmParen <- function(e) {
    if (length(e) > 1) {
        if (identical(e[[1]], as.symbol("("))) e <- e[[2]]
        if (length(e) > 1) for (i in 1:length(e)) e[[i]] <- Recall(e[[i]])
    }
    e
}

s <- "( ((  A  ) *  J ) - ((  J  ) *  G  ) ) /  Z "
rmParen(parse(text = s)[[1]])
```

The last line returns:

```
(A * J - J * G)/Z
```

This works in all cases I tried but you might want to test it out a bit more.

If you want a character string as the return value then use `deparse` as in `deparse(rmParen(parse(text = s)[[1]]))`.  Note that `deparse` has a `width.cutoff` argument which is set to 60 by default but can be set to be larger if the actual expressions exceed that length.

**Ryacas**

```
library(Ryacas)

s <- "( ((  A  ) *  J ) - ((  J  ) *  G  ) ) /  Z "
Simplify(s)
```

The last line returns:

```
expression((A - G) * J/Z)
```

Note that its actually the print method that invokes the computation so if you want to save it then try `yacas(Simplify(s))$text` or `as.character(yacas(Simplify(s)))` .

ADDED: Ryacas solution.

Comment: Thanks! The first solution works great, I made a wrapper which works well on my data: `rmp <- function(s){paste(deparse(rmParen(parse(text = s)[[1]])), collapse="")}`. I haven't gotten the Ryacas solution to work yet, but the first one does just what I want!

Comment: If you are having problems getting Ryacas to work see the Troubleshooting section on the home page: http://ryacas.googlecode.com

Comment: The first solution has a bug; it removes too many parentheses on some occasions. Eg, try it with `s <- "((a + b) * (c + d))/2"` I guess this is because it's ignorant of R's operator precedence rules. The Ryacas solution should be immune to this, though.

Comment: @Hong, `rmParens(parse(text = "((a + b) * (c + d))/2")[[1]])` returns `(a + b) * (c + d)/2` which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

We can use R parser to do the job. The trick is that R knows when parentheses are needed based on the parse tree, so we can simply *remove* them from the tree:

See this:

```
simplify <- function(e)
{
    if( mode(e) %in% c("name","numeric") ) return(e)

    op <- as.character(e[[1]])

    if( op == "(" ) return(simplify(e[[2]]))

    if( op %in% c("+","-","*","/","^") ) return(call(op, simplify(e[[2]]), simplify(e[[3]])))
}

simplifytext <- function(s) deparse(simplify(parse(text=s)[[1]]))
```

Inputs:

```
str <- "( ((  A  ) *  J ) - ((  J  ) *  G  ) ) /  Z "
str2 <- gsub("-", "/", gsub("*", "+", str, fixed=TRUE))
```

Results:

```
> str2
[1] "( ((  A  ) +  J ) / ((  J  ) +  G  ) ) /  Z "

> simplifytext(str)
[1] "(A * J - J * G)/Z"
> simplifytext(str2)
[1] "(A + J)/(J + G)/Z"
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works on all my data! I'd accept both solutions if I could, but G. Grothendieck was 15 minutes earlier...

Comment: @user1981275, Fair enough! :-) If you have interest, check the following answer, with some examples for further simplifications that can be carried out symbolically in R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725930/using-matrices-algebra-to-manipulate-strings-is-it-feasible/15747856#15747856